# What do you call a small confined space in prison where inmates "walk"?

Tags: word-request

What do you call a small confined space or yard in prison where inmates "walk", so to speak? Like this one

[image]

Comment: a small and confined *yard*, in a prison.

Comment: @JamesK Is there a more specific term?

Comment: I only know 'prison yard'.